# Virtual Assistant unable to dispatch new QnA maker knowledge base

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am creating a virtual agent from the BOT framework virtual assistant template and created a new QnA maker knowledge base. Added the new kb to the cognitivemodels.json and ran the update_cognitive_models script with -remotetolocal paramter. I can see that the LUIS dispatch has been updated and published with the new kb, which is multi-turn, but in the emulator the LUIS trace is performed, the intent is found but the bot won't search the QnA maker kb to start the dialog while the Faq kb works without issue. Here is the LUIS Trace:

```
{
  "recognizerResult": {
    "alteredText": null,
    "entities": {},
    "intents": {
      "q_Intune_Enrollment": {
        "score": 0.8491236
      }
    },
    "text": "Intune"
  }
}
```

```
This is all it performs:
[09:12:37]-> message Intune
[09:12:37]<- traceLuisV3 Trace
[09:12:37]POST200conversations/<conversationId>/activities/<activityId>
[09:12:37]<- typing
[09:12:37]POST200conversations/<conversationId>/activities/<activityId>
[09:12:38]<- message Apologies, it looks like something went wrong. Try...
```

Update: Issue was raised in GITHUB and solution was provided.